# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'movies-detail' with arguments '('Dark',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<name>[^/]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

i want to pass the 2 url tags but get the error in that

```
{% for movie in movies %}
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <a href="{% url 'movies-detail' movie.name %}">
            <img class="rounded mb-3 mb-md-0"  src="{{ movie.image.url }}" height="200" width="400" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'movies-detail' movie.name movie.id %}">{{ movie.name }} {{ movie.id }}</a></h2>
             <h4 class="text-muted">Released Date : {{ movie.date_released|date:"F d, Y " }}</h4>
            <h4 class="article-title" >Producer : {{ movie.producer }}</h4>
            <h4 class="article-title" >Director : {{ movie.director }}</h4>

        </div>
      </div>
            <p> {% ratings movie %}</p>

<hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

want to receive that in the urls.py and show that

urlpatterns = [

```
path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='blog-about'),
path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-post'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
path('post/new/<str:name>/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
path('', MoviesListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
path('<str:name>/<int:id>/',MoviesDetailListView.as_view(), name='movies-detail'),
path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
```

]

Comment: Can you post  all the urls?

Comment: why are there so many spaces after `movie.name` ? from the error your url only seems to catch movie.name(missing seconds parameter). Please add only 1 space after movie.name

Comment: with the only single space it gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with arguments '('Dark',)'` is telling you that you have only provided the name, not the id.

Add `movie.id` to the first link.

```
<a href="{% url 'movies-detail' movie.name movie.id %}">
```

The second link to the `movies-detail` page already looks corect.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you should get a different error. If you really get the same error, then you haven't saved your changes and restarted the server, or you have another `{% url %}` tag with the same problem.

Comment: thanks you are right i have it in 2 places that's why it raise that error

Answer (score 1):

You error is due to the first tag `<a href="{% url 'movies-detail' movie.name %}">`. You're only providing one positional parameter in which it requires two.

Add an additional url for this particular url tag but with a separate `name`.

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [path('about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='blog-about'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/<str:name>/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('', MoviesListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('<str:name>/<int:id>/',MoviesDetailListView.as_view(), name='movies-detail'),
    path('<str:name>/',MoviesDetailListView.as_view(), name='movies-detail-name'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
]
```

Comment: Removed. Was a typo on my behalf.